# Why only 1 answer per user per question?

Tags: discussion

Why do users have to edit their preexisting answer instead of adding a new one? Even if their previous answer is incorrect, what if they had already received votes? Those votes don't seem relevant anymore if the answer is completely different.

EDIT: I was wrong. You can add another. Oversite on my point. Someone should close this.

Comment: As answered below, you are welcome to add multiple answers to the same question. However, the only time you would want to provide a second answer is if it's an entirely different solution than the other one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Users can easily add multiple answers.

If you scroll to the bottom of a page for which you have already posted an answer, you will notice a button similar to this one:

[image]

This will display the following prompt:

[image]

Selecting "OK" will then display the editor for composing another answer.